# reg expression starting at a specific squence number?

Tags: php, regex, sequence

I have created a reg expression to find all files in a directory whose file name starts with "installation" and has 6 numbers after that.

What I am looking to do is get a list of files name beginning with "*installation*" with only 6 numbers after it. For instance, right now I have six files (test files):

```
installation.php
installation000001.php
installation000002.php
installation000003-sweep.php
installation000004.php
installation-sweep.php
```

the expression that I am using with php is `/^installation([0-9]{6})/` which pulls:

```
installation000001.php
installation000002.php
installation000003-sweep.php
installation000004.php
```

I only want to pull 1, 2 and 4 (not installation000003-sweep.php). Also, how can I start from 000002 that would only pull:

```
installation000002.php
installation000004.php
```

?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want the ones with numbers then .php:

```
/installation([0-9]{6}).php/
```

Combine it with starting at 2 you can just do:

```
/installation([0-9]{5}[2-9]).php/
```

Comment: I can work with this. However, I will have to use variable data once the sequence gets above 000009. So if I have a file named "installation000012" and a file named "installation000014" I can use "/^installation([0-9]{4}[1-9]{2}).php/". The variable data would be "/^installation([#-9]{#}[#-9]{#}).php/" (all of the pound signs). I can figure out the variable data from the start of the sequence number. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use positive/negative lookaheads:

```
/^installation([0-9]{6})(?=\.)/
                         ^^^^ followed by a period
/^installation([0-9]{6})(?!-)/
                         ^^^^ not followed by a dash
```

The easiest way to exclude the first record is to use [array_splice](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-splice.php) or [array_shift()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-shift.php) on the result array instead of using a rule in your pattern.